# Kotlin Compose Web project not loading the main js file

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to follow the [Compose Multiplatform Web](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Web/Getting_Started) Getting Started guide. Most of it seems to work fine, but when I try to actually run the thing (`gradle jsBrowserRun`), it starts a browser, but it can't find the generated JavaScript file. The browser console shows a 404 for `GET http://localhost:8080/kotlin-multi-web.js`.

The file `kotlin-multi-web.js` is indeed the name of a file generated in `web/build/compileSync/main/developmentExecutable/kotlin`.

The page title matches the one I defined in my `index.html`, so that gets loaded correctly.

I have tried a pure Compose Web project (which isn't a Gradle multi module project), and there it does all load correctly. I checked, and didn't see any differences between the Gradle build files other than the extra dependency from the `web` project on `common`.

So, why doesn't it load, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I couldn't find a tag specifically covering Compose Multiplatform Web, if someone knows please add it.

Comment: Can you attach a link to your project? What browser do you use?

Comment: @vanyochek I have uploaded it to https://github.com/jorn86/fox-kotlin-multi. The error happens in both Firefox and Chromium

Comment: Thank you! I reproduced the problem. Please file an issue https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/issues.

Comment: @vanyochek Done: https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/issues/2380